# Jackson InvalidDefinitionException on deserializing Set

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, java-11

I'm running to InvalidDefinitionException when deserializing Set.

**JDK11 / Jackson 2.12 / Lombok 1.18**

```
@Data(staticConstructor = "of")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Task {

    @NonNull
    private final Set<Category> categories;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.ImmutableCollections$Set12` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no default no-arguments constructor found

at [Source: (String)"categories":["java.util.ImmutableCollections$Set12",["Category1"]] (through reference chain:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1764) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1209) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createUsingDefault(ValueInstantiator.java:248) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createUsingDefault(StdValueInstantiator.java:275) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createDefaultInstance(CollectionDeserializer.java:262) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:120) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserializeWithType(CollectionDeserializer.java:283) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:539) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:565) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:449) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1405) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:362) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:195) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:542) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:565) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:449) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1405) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:362) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:195) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:?]
```

It's not happening all the time.

Most of the time class gets serialized as

```
"categories": [
"java.util.HashSet",
[
"Catergory1"
]
]
```

Issue happens when it gets serialized as

```
"categories": [
"java.util.ImmutableCollections$Set12",
[
"Catergory1"
]
]
```

It's strange that it happens only few times.

Found this bug report but not sure if it's related
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2900

Comment: Looks relevant. Possible to track, what is the source of the serialized data? Might be possible if that is using the `Set.of` for one or two elements assigned to `categories`.

Comment: There's a task creator component that's responsible for creating tasks and yes it's using Set.of() static factory method.

Comment: If you own its implementation, then you already know the solution for it. Else, might be worth asking about the release date again. It's almost the end of Q2 as proposed in the thread.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for confirming the root cause.